# Add Submit button on Orbeon Form Runner and then call custom Java REST API on submission

Tags: orbeon, xforms, formbuilder

I am working on a POC (proof of concept) where I am evaluating Orbeon form builder/runner. I am using community edition, just in case, I will need to change the code, else the Professional Edition would do for POC.

I am integrating FormRunner with my web application running on different web server, which will call the FormRunner URL with some custom query parameters.

I want to remove the Summary, PDF and Review buttons from FormRunner and simply want the save button to function as submit button, so as clicking on it will submit the POST data to my custom Java code which will talk back to my web application, likely through REST API. The submit button then should redirect me to another page saying 'Your data has been submitted'.

I find it difficult to understand the area where I can change the code for expected behavior. Could you provide me some pointers in this regards please?

Thanks and Regards, 
Mayuresh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't have to change the code for this, but instead use the [`oxf.fr.detail.buttons.*.*`](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/configuration-properties/configuration-properties-form-runner#TOC-Buttons-on-the-detail-page) property to define which buttons are shown. Based on your description, you only need the [`workflow-send`](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/configuration-properties/configuration-properties-form-runner#TOC-Workflow-send-button) button, which, amongst other things can POST the form data to a service you specify.

Comment: Thanks @avernet, this exactly what I was looking for. The oxf.fr.detail.buttons.*.* did the trick. 

With one more property below, I am processing the form data in doPost() method of my custom servlet mapped with /createPost URI.
<property as="xs:anyURI" name="oxf.fr.detail.send.uri.*.*" value="/createPost"/>

Comment: Going ahead from previous solution, now my form has an attachment control, where I upload an xhtml file which I later use in the doPost() method. I retrieve and parse form.xhtml to get the path of attachment. Earlier I used to get from form.xhtml, "/fr/service/persistence/crud/orbeon/builder/data/.../aca4b...63f0.bin", however suddenly I started getting a different path "//file:/C:/tomcat/temp/xforms_upload_2254538366948889108.tmp?filename=template.xhtml&mediatype=application%2Fxhtml%2Bxml&size=891&mac=9c0a...7563". Not sure what went wrong.

Comment: In short, following is happening at my end ...
http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-controls/upload-control#TOC-Upload-as-a-URL

While I am looking for attachment URL like ...
http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/integration#TOC-Attachments

Comment: @MayureshVaze Are you saying that when using the `workflow-send` button, the form data is sent to the service you specified, but when data was attached to the form, paths point to local files, instead of pointing to the location of the file in the persistence layer?

Comment: I am processing POST data sent by workflow-send. However the attachment URL doesn't come from this POST data. Instead, I extract form.xhtml and parse for my attachment URL.

`<xf:instance id="fr-form-instance">
    <post-template filename="template.xhtml" mediatype="application/xhtml+xml" size="8437">/fr/service/persistence/crud/orbeon/builder/data/.../aca4...63f0.bin</post-template>
</xf:instance>`

But suddenly I started getting this value as "//file:/C:/tomcat/temp/xforms_upload_225...108.tmp?filename=template.xhtml&mediatype=application%2Fxhtml%2Bxml&size=891&mac=9c0a...7563".

Comment: Snippet of my service class (doPost() of my custom servlet) which get called after user clicks on button of type workflo-send

`String formurl = contextUrl + "/fr/service/persistence/crud/" + app + "/" + form + "/form/form.xhtml";
InputStream formin = new URL(formurl).openStream(); 
itemMap = domparser.parseDocument(formin);
String template = itemMap.get("post-template");`

Comment: I used to get template = "/fr/service/persistence/crud/orbeon/builder/data/38d96362a05145a52eac2a4593d2c5719780cd54/aca4bdca799f4c821e8cc5cc891debeba7a963f0.bin"
but now, I am getting template = "file:/C:/tomcat/temp/xforms_upload_2831826303033975948.tmp?filename=template.xhtml&amp;mediatype=application%2Fxhtml%2Bxml&amp;size=891&amp;mac=b6ac347cc3c6ff70f14e90905498d4d766b7a4ea"

Comment: @mavaze So you're saying that the deployed form `/fr/service/persistence/crud/your-app/your-form/form/form.xhtml` contains a `//file:/C:/tomcat/…`? That should not be the case. In 4.0, the attachment should be moved to `your-app/your-form` on publish and shouldn't be in `orbeon/builder` anymore. So the path should look something like `/fr/service/persistence/crud/your-app/your-form/form/9990d9d2ac2da178caf80fb1aaaa3f12f00c9643.bin`. I tried this now, and it works for me. Which version are you using>